# Sorting a time intervals

Tags: java, algorithm

I am giving a time interval in the form of two arrays.

```
A[0]=  2  B[0]=3
A[1]=  9  B[1]=11
A[2] = 5 B[2]=6
A[3] = 3 B[3]=10
```

I want to sort the interval on the basics of starting time i.e.

```
(2,3) , (3,10) ,(5,6) ,(9,11)
```

Does i have to make a structure of this. or it can be done straight.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What did you try?

Comment: its straight forward. Just sort them based on array `A[]`

Comment: If the array size is fairly smaller, you can use insertion sort on first array, while swapping elements from first array, swap the second arrays elements also. Otherwise it would be better to wrap them into an object and put each object into collection, and then use `Collections.sort`

Comment: @arunmoezhi what about B i will lost the maping of A in B

Comment: of course, you need to take care of that. When you sort `A[]`, you need to keep track of the original indices. The sorted values of `A[]` are `2,3,5,9` and their original indices are `0,3,2,1`. Use these values to print the elements of `B[]` array.

Comment: Is HashTable is needed

Comment: try to use fancy data structures only when you really need them. So the answer is `no` for a hashtable

Comment: @arunmoezhi here a collection of tuples implementing comparison seems the most sane solution. This is not what I would call a fancy data structure. At least it has the merit of clarity and be easier to understand than raw numeric arrays.

Comment: I was saying 'no' for hash table.  Not for any comparison based sorting method.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done straight, since you dont show what have you tried so far I just give you the algorithm:

```
for j = 1 to n
    for i = i+1 to n
        if(A[i]>A[j]){
            swap(A[i],A[j])
            swap(B[i],B[j])
        }
```

you can easily convert it to java code.

this algorithm is buble sort if you want better algorithm use this wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) to improve your time.

As DwB want here is merge sort full java code that do what you want. I got merge sort algorithm from [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html)  and modify to satisfy your need. also you could see the working version on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/SA1Rs0)

**Merge Sort:**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone
{
    private int[] A;
    private int[] B;
    private int[] helperA;
    private int[] helperB;

    private int length;

    public static void main (String[] args){
        int[] As = {2,9,5,3};
        int[] Bs = {3,11,6,10};
        new Ideone().sort(As,Bs);
    }

    public void sort(int[] As , int[] Bs) {
        A = As;
        B = Bs;
        length = A.length;
        this.helperA = new int[length];
        this.helperB = new int[length];
        mergesort(0, length - 1);
        for(int i = 0 ; i<length ; i++)
        System.out.println("(" + A[i] + "," + B[i]+  ")");
    }

    private void mergesort(int low, int high) {
        // check if low issmaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
        if (low < high) {
        // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        // Sort the left side of the array
        mergesort(low, middle);
        // Sort the right side of the array
        mergesort(middle + 1, high);
        // Combine them both
        merge(low, middle, high);
        }
    }

    private void merge(int low, int middle, int high) {

        // Copy both parts into the helper array
        for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
            helperA[i] = A[i];
            helperB[i] = B[i];
        }

        int i = low;
        int j = middle + 1;
        int k = low;
        // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
        // to the original array
        while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
            if (helperA[i] <= helperA[j]) {
                A[k] = helperA[i];
                B[k] = helperB[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                A[k] = helperA[j];
                B[k] = helperB[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
        while (i <= middle) {
            A[k] = helperA[i];
            B[k] = helperB[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great example of the worst possible sorting technique; bubble sort.

Comment: simple solution, bad complexity. I guess you can modify this to use a sorting method having time complexity as `O(nlogn)`. But anyway, an upvote for giving a simple solution to begin with

Comment: @DwB since he didnt mention anything about time complexity I just gave him what he want, I just show him that he could sort A and then he have B sorted. Internet is full of sort algorithm if he wants to make this better he could easily google it.

Comment: Bubble sort is only acceptable as an answer if the question is "what is the worst possible solution to sort this data".  other that that, it is never acceptable.

Comment: @DwB sry it took so long, I was cooking dinner ;) now check my answer, I hope it is right on your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
private static class StartEnd implements Comparable<StartEnd> {
    private final int start;
    private final int end;
    // + constructor + getters
    @Override
    public int compareTo(StartEnd other) {
        return start - other.getStart();
    }
}

public void sort(int[] starts, int[] ends) {
    StartEnd[] ses = new StartEnd[starts.length];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < starts.length ; ++i) {
        ses[i] = new StartEnd(starts[i], ends[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(sis);
    // re-insert
    for(int i = 0 ; i < ses.length ; ++i) {
        starts[i] = ses[i].getStart;
        ends[i] = ses[i].getEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: why this line of code `return start - other.getStart();`

Comment: If you write the getter, ``other.getStart()`` is equivalent to ``other.start``

Answer (score 0):

instead having two arrays, create object which holds your intervals

```
class Interval  implements Comparable<Interval>  {

private Long start,completed

 public Interval(Long start, Long completed) {
        this.start = start;
        this.completed = completed;
}


  @Override
  public int compareTo(Interval o) {
    return start.compareTo(o.start);
  }

//getters and setters ommited
}
```

then, all what you need to do is implement `compareTo` method and put all your data in some collection ie `List<Interval> intervals`

and used `Collections.sort(intervals)` to sort them

**EDIT**

Example:

originally you have:

```
A[0]=  2  B[0]=3,
A[1]=  9  B[1]=11
A[2] = 5 B[2]=6
A[3] = 3 B[3]=10`
```

lets replace this by:

```
List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
intervals.add(new Interval(2L,3L));
intervals.add(new Interval(9L,11L));
intervals.add(new Interval(5L,6L));
intervals.add(new Interval(3L,10L));
//NOTE L is added at the end variable as interval uses Long, if you change it to integer you dont need to add it;
```

And now all what you need to do is sort

```
Collection.sort(intervals);
```

Comment: would you give me a example

Comment: @user4084025 here is your example, have a look

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Java is an object oriented language; learn to use objects.

Possible class for the time interval

```
public class TimeInterval implements Comparable<TimeInterval>
{
    private int end;
    private int start;

    public TimeInterval(
        final int end,
        final int start)
    {
        this.end = end;
        this.start = start;
    }

    public int getEnd()
    {
        return end;
    }

    public int getStart()
    {
        return start;
    }

    public int comareTo(final TimeInterval other)
    {
        if (other == null)
        {
            return -1; // this will put the null value objects at the end.
        }

        return start - other.start;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The classical Javanese "object oriented" approach for this is to use a dedicated class storing a pair of values (`int` values, in this case), and sort them, as already pointed out in most of the other answers. However, I'd recommend to **not** make this class `Comparable`. Instead, a `Comparator` could be used, which would make it much easier to introduce new sorting orders. Particularly, there could be `Comparator` implementations for sorting in ascending/descending order, based on the first/second value, respectively. Only then, object orientation plays out its advantages, compensating the "disadvantage" of having to create such a pair of `int` values as a "dummy data structure" in the first place...

However, I wanted to try to find a solution for the original question as well, namely, sorting two arrays "in sync". Despite the task of sorting seemingly being trivial, one can dedicate a lot of work to *doing it right* (see [Chapter 3 of TAOCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming)). A bubble sort is simple but inefficient even for medium-sized arrays. Implementing a quick- or merge sort can be fiddly when trying to get the indices right. However, one solution can be obtained by simply taking the existing `sort` method from `java.lang.Arrays`, and factoring out the most elementary building block: The `swap` function:

```
public class ArraySort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int A[] = new int[4];
        final int B[] = new int[4];
        A[0] = 2;  B[0] = 3;
        A[1] = 9;  B[1] = 11;
        A[2] = 5;  B[2] = 6;
        A[3] = 3;  B[3] = 10;

        Swapper swapper = new Swapper()
        {
            @Override
            public void swap(int array[], int i0, int i1)
            {
                ArraySort.swap(A, i0, i1);
                ArraySort.swap(B, i0, i1);
            }
        };
        sort(A, 0, A.length, swapper);

        for (int i=0; i<A.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("("+A[i]+","+B[i]+")");
        }
    }

    interface Swapper
    {
        void swap(int array[], int i0, int i1);
    }

    public static void swap(int array[], int i0, int i1)
    {
        int t = array[i0];
        array[i0] = array[i1];
        array[i1] = t;
    }

    // The following methods are copied from java.util.Arrays:
    public static void sort(int x[], int off, int len, Swapper swapper)
    {
        if (len < 7)
        {
            for (int i = off; i < len + off; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i; j > off && x[j - 1] > x[j]; j--)
                {
                    swapper.swap(x, j, j - 1);
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        int m = off + (len >> 1);
        if (len > 7)
        {
            int l = off;
            int n = off + len - 1;
            if (len > 40)
            { 
                int s = len / 8;
                l = med3(x, l, l + s, l + 2 * s);
                m = med3(x, m - s, m, m + s);
                n = med3(x, n - 2 * s, n - s, n);
            }
            m = med3(x, l, m, n);
        }
        int v = x[m];

        int a = off, b = a, c = off + len - 1, d = c;
        while (true)
        {
            while (b <= c && x[b] <= v)
            {
                if (x[b] == v)
                {
                    swapper.swap(x, a++, b);
                }
                b++;
            }
            while (c >= b && x[c] >= v)
            {
                if (x[c] == v)
                {
                    swapper.swap(x, c, d--);
                }
                c--;
            }
            if (b > c)
            {
                break;
            }
            swapper.swap(x, b++, c--);
        }

        int s, n = off + len;
        s = Math.min(a - off, b - a);
        vecswap(x, off, b - s, s, swapper);
        s = Math.min(d - c, n - d - 1);
        vecswap(x, b, n - s, s, swapper);

        if ((s = b - a) > 1)
        {
            sort(x, off, s, swapper);
        }
        if ((s = d - c) > 1)
        {
            sort(x, n - s, s, swapper);
        }
    }

    private static void vecswap(int x[], int a, int b, int n, Swapper swapper)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++, a++, b++)
        {
            swapper.swap(x, a, b);
        }
    }

    private static int med3(int x[], int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return (x[a] < x[b] ? (x[b] < x[c] ? b : x[a] < x[c] ? c : a)
            : (x[b] > x[c] ? b : x[a] > x[c] ? c : a));
    }

}
```

---

### Notes

This is not a solution that I would recommend. It's just an attempt to answer the question

> or it can be done straight. [sic!]

And the answer is: Yes, it is possible, although the solutions that are introducing some sort of an `IntPair` are more idiomatic.

Apart from that, it would probably be more efficient to "inline" the `Swapper#swap` calls to directly swap elements of two arrays that are stored in instance variables, or passed as method parameters. However, I liked the genericity of such a `Swapper` interface. Additionally, it would be nice to generalize this even further, by passing in something like a

```
interface IntArrayEntryComparator {
    int compare(int array[], int i0, int i1);
}
```

But the latter would go beyond what I wanted to test/demonstrate with this class.