# Merge Sort on an ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, camera

I'm working on a method that sorts my array list using merge sort. My problem is that it will not sort the array list the way i want it t(By total number of times the word appears). It seems as if it is sorting it but when i debug it reverts back to alphabetical order at the end.

Edit: To clarify: the variable "temp" is an instance variable. This is the ArrayList that we are trying to sort.

code:

```
public void mergeSortFreq(ArrayList<Term> toDo, int first, int mid, int last) {
    int first1 = first;
    int last1 = mid;
    int first2 = mid + 1;
    int last2 = last;
    int index = first1;
    ArrayList<Term> temp = new ArrayList<Term>();
    int counter = 0;
    while ((first1 <= last1) && (first2 < last2)) {
        if (toDo.get(first1).compareTo(toDo.get(first2).getTotalFrequency()) <= 0) {
            temp.add(toDo.get(first1));
            first1++;
            counter++;
        } else {
            temp.add(toDo.get(first2));
            first2++;
        }
        index++;
    }

    while (first1 < last1) {
        temp.add(toDo.get(first1));
        first1++;
        index++;
    }

    while (first2 < last2) {
        temp.add(toDo.get(first2));
        first2++;
        index++;
    }

    for(index = first; index < temp.size(); ++index){
            terms.set(index, temp.get(index));
    }
}

public void mergeFreqhelp(ArrayList<Term> toDo, int first, int last) {
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if (first < last) {
        mergeFreqhelp(toDo, first, mid);
        mergeFreqhelp(toDo, mid + 1, last);
        mergeSortFreq(toDo, first, mid, last);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Working???");
    }
}
```

Comment: there's no point in re-implementing sorting in Java, built-in sort will be faster and less error-prone

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125557/sorting-a-time-intervals/26125685#26125685 in this I implement a merge sort, just ignore B and helperB, this variable are for answering that question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope problem. You are not returning and assigning the result of sorting from `mergeSortFreq`. Change that method so that it returns an ArrayList. Otherwise the sorting will take place within the method, but will never be returned back.

Comment: The argument `toDo` is a reference to an object. Changing on its content should also also be available out of the method, right?

Comment: `toDo` is a reference object. But `temp` (which is the sorting result) only exists within the scope of `mergeSortFreq`.

Answer (score 0):

Current posted code for method `mergeSortFreq(...)` is incomplete. The variable `terms` doesn't exist and once the function returns, the argument `toDo` remains the same.

You may consider transfering the contents from `temp` to `toDo` before returning.

- I would have added this as a comment, but I don't have permissions yet.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that `temp` was an instance variable - and that is what you expected to be being sorted?

However, in your `mergeSortFreq` method, you have the line:

```
ArrayList<Term> temp = new ArrayList<Term>();
```

This creates a locally scoped variable that will shadow any instance variables - so all modifications you make to temp, are just made to the locally scoped list - not the instance variable, so are lost once you finish the method.

Just change the line in mergeFreqSort so it just resets the instance variable:

```
temp = new ArrayList<Term>();
```

(if you wanted to consider a cleaner, recursive implementation, you could look at [this version](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/10/mergesort-java-implementation.html))