# Sorting intervals in java

Tags: java

I am giving a time interval in the form of a input file  .

```
INPUT FILE
2 3   //First  start time and second one end time
5 6
9 11
3 10
```

I want to sort the interval on the basics of start time i.e.

```
(2,3) , (3,10) ,(5,6) ,(9,11)
```

Does i have to make a structure of this. or it can be done straight.
My approach:

```
class Interval implements Comparable<Interval>{

        private int start , end;
        public Interval(int start , int end){
            this.start = start;
            this.end = end;
        }
        public int compareTo(Interval o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(o==null)
                return -1;
            return  start-o.start;
        }


    }
```

I am not getting the output of it.
**Is there any better method**
Please HElp me.

Comment: What output are you getting? Please show the code where you actually sort the intervals.

Comment: you asked this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125557/sorting-a-time-intervals yesterday, please do some work your self it is not the place, that people do your homework!

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with this `compareTo()` method. Seems to be you don't know how to use it.
You should use it in this way.

```
public class Interval implements Comparable<Interval>{
private int start , end;
public Interval(int start , int end){
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
public int compareTo(Interval o) {
    if(o==null)
        return -1;
    return  start-o.start;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Interval{" +
            "start=" + start +
            ", end=" + end +
            '}';
  }
}
```

Now how to use?

```
  Interval interval1 = new Interval(2, 3);
  Interval interval2 = new Interval(5, 6);
  Interval interval3 = new Interval(9, 11);
  Interval interval4 = new Interval(3, 10);

  List<Interval> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(interval1);
  list.add(interval2);
  list.add(interval3);
  list.add(interval4);

  System.out.println(list);
  Collections.sort(list);
  System.out.println(list);
```

Out put:

```
  [Interval{start=2, end=3}, Interval{start=5, end=6}, Interval{start=9, end=11}, Interval{start=3, end=10}]
  [Interval{start=2, end=3}, Interval{start=3, end=10}, Interval{start=5, end=6}, Interval{start=9, end=11}]
```

Comment: is there any better method to sort the intervals

Comment: @user4084025 this way is better. You have to use either `Comparable` or `Comparator`. If you use `Comparator` you have to override `compare()`

Answer (score 0):

You need call `Collection.sort(list);` in case using lists. You can also use `SortedSet` or `TreeMap` to keep your collections sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Your `compareTo()` method works. Use `Collections.sort()` and you are good to go.

```
    List<Interval> intervals = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    intervals.add(new Interval(2, 3));
    intervals.add(new Interval(5, 6));
    intervals.add(new Interval(9, 11));
    intervals.add(new Interval(3, 10));
    Collections.sort(intervals);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your sample code in Java 8. I am getting error on sort: The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Interval>)

Comment: You could try using [`List.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) which is introduced in Java 8, e.g. `intervals.sort();`

Answer (score 0):

The class Integer has a compare function that can do the comparing for you

```
class Interval implements Comparable<Interval>{

  ....

  public int compareTo(Interval o) {
    return Integer.compare(start, o.start);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Interval implements Comparable<Interval>{

    private int start , end;

    public Interval(int start , int end){
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }
    public int compareTo(Interval o) {
        if(o==null)
            return -1;
       return Integer.compare(o.start, this.start);
    }
}

public void test(){

    Interval[] ar = new Interval[4];
    ar[0] = new Interval(1,2);
    ar[1] = new Interval(10,2);
    ar[2] = new Interval(2,2);
    ar[3] = new Interval(94,2);
    Arrays.sort(ar);
    for(int i=0, len=ar.length; i<len; i++){
        System.out.println("( "+ar[i].start+" ,"+ar[i].end+")");
    }

}
```